# For Loops for a Time Class

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop for a time class. Where if the minutes entered are over 60, 60 is subtracted from the total minutes and hours is incremented by 1 until the final minutes left is less than 60 . I was doing if statements like

```
if (m > 59){
    m = m - 60;
    h++;      

    if (m > 59)... etc..
```

but that doesn't cover every case and I feel like I should know how to do this for loop but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Thank you all, I'm using Jendas but everyone's answer helped me understand what I'm doing much better

Comment: If some answer suits you and you consider it correct, don't forget to accept it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if it doesn't have to be implemented using loops, you could do simply

```
h = m / 60;
m = m % 60;
```

It is the fastest and cleanest way to do that, I suppose.

Not really sure whether you want to do anything else inside the loops. If so, this won't help you very much.

**Edit:**
Here is some explanation of how it works. 
What `m / 60` does is called integer division. It returns floor of the expression. So for example if `m = 131` than `m / 60 = 2`.

The second expression uses the modulo operator. Basically it finds the reminder after division. Back to our example, `m % 60 = 11` since m can be written as `m = 60 * 2 + 11 = 131`. For further information please refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: so say I needed to do this for seconds to minutes also, it would be m = s/60;  s = s % 60

Comment: Yes. It would be exactly like that.

Answer (score 0):

@Jendas has a good simple answer to the overall problem, but if you want to keep with this format but fix your issue with loops, you could put the whole thing in a while loop instead of individual if statements:

```
while(m >59)
{
    m = m - 60;
    h++;
    // do anything else you need to take care of
}
// finishing statements
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = 0;  
while (m >= 60)
{
    m = m - 60;
    h++;
}
```

You probably want to use >= 60 instead of 59.
Also, as Jendas rightly suggested you might want to research a little about the modulus operator '%'